# How to load different Fragments by using SideNavigation SAPUI5

Tags: fragment, sapui5

[image: My first try (screenshot)]

I  have already implemented a SideNavigation inside the WebIDE using SAPUI5. Additionally, I integrated the select Event for NavigationListItems as well as an empty panel for the fragments inside an HBox (consists of SideNavigation, Panel (id="FragmentPanel")). My problem occurs while trying to write code for the Controller.

I want the panel to change its content by clicking/ selecting one of my NavigationListItems so that the correct fragment will be displayed in the content area. But I have absolutely no idea how that works. I've seen that there is a destroyContent & an addContent Method but I'm an absolute beginner.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why do you want to load different fragments, if you want to show different data based on item click of a table, you should use splitapp scenario : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.SplitApp/preview